# Looping a single sentence by a user - entered integer

Tags: python, loops, variables, integer, int

So I was given a problem by my Computer Science teacher, but I have been sat here for ages and cannot for the life of me figure it out. There are plenty of tasks within the problem, but there is only one I'm having trouble with.

So, I am coding a program for a carpet shop, and the part that I am stuck on is this.

2: For each floor you need to carpet, ask the user for the name of the room that the floor is located in. 
Basically X number of rooms; need to loop a sentence asking for the name of the room multiplied by X. So if the user has 3 rooms they need carpeted, I would end up with the name of 3 rooms (Lounge, Bedroom etc.), and be able to display these results back to the user later. Here is what I have so far...

```
#Generating An Estimate. 

#Welcome message + setting base price to 0 + defining "getting_estimate" variable.
def getting_estimate ():
    overallPrice = 0
    print("Welcome!")

#Getting the information about the customer.
    custID = input ("\n1. Please enter the customer's ID: ")
    estimateDate = input ("\n2. Please enter the date: ")
    numberOfRooms = input (int("\n3. Please enter the number of rooms that need to be carpeted: "))

#Add input allowing user to enter the 
#name of the room, looped by the integer entered
#in the Variable "numberOfRooms", and possibly
#adding 1st room, 2nd room etc??
```

If someone can work this out they are helping me loads. Thanks :)

Comment: You want `numberOfRooms = int(input("blah blah"))` not `numberOfRooms = input(int("blah blah"))`.  You are trying to cast your message to the user as an integer, but really it's the user's response that you want to cast to integer.

Comment: This is a pretty good example of where looking at the exact error output is informative. I'm guessing that you get a `ValueError` but it's best to not leave us guessing, by adding in the exact error output it makes it a lot easier to answer your question. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for info on how to improve writing questions.

Comment: I would, but the code doesn't have a useful error, as I am asking for how to continue it, not what it wrong with it. Thanks though:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using a for loop perhaps?

```
    for i in range(numberOfrooms):
        roomName = input("Blah blah")
```

Full code:

```
def getting_estimate ():
overallPrice = 0
print("Welcome!")

custID = input ("\n1. Please enter the customer's ID: ")
estimateDate = input ("\n2. Please enter the date: ")
numberOfRooms = int (input("\n3. Please enter the number of rooms that need to be carpeted: "))
cust_roster = {custID:[]}
for i in range(numberOfRooms):
    roomName = input("Enter the name of room number "+str(i+1))
    cust_roster[custID].append(roomName)
print("{} has {} rooms called: {}".format(custID,
                                          len(cust_roster[custID]),
                                          cust_roster[custID]))
```

Btw I'm doing a similar task for my OCR computing coursework ;) so good luck!

Comment: Thanks man, that worked! Good luck in your coursework, I'm starting mine soon too, I'm with Edexcel